# Copiar algunos elementos de un HashMap a otro

Tags: java, hashmap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Necesito copiar solo algunos elementos de un Hashmap que contiene una lista de objetos denominados Criatura cuya Key es un atributo llamado ID. Necesito recorrer el hashmap mapaCriaturas y si su algún atributo Fortaleza coincide con un valor pasado por el usuario de valor N esa criatura debería guardarse en este nuevo hashmap.

La idea que tengo es que como la clave es un String ,y es el id, es recuperar ese ID y luego e objeto para pasárselo como segundo argumento pero esto no me funciona.

PD: ¿Podría borrar ese elemento que guardo en el nuevo hashmap del viejo?

Muchas gracias.

```
//private Map<String,Criatura> mapaCriaturas = new HashMap<String,Criatura>(); Esta es la declaración del principal HashMap

HashMap <String, Criatura> map = new HashMap <String, Criatura> ();
HashMap x = new HashMap <String,Criatura> ();

 Set<String> keys = mapaCriaturas.keySet();
for (String k:keys){
    System.out.println(k+" "+mapaCriaturas.get(k));
    System.out.println("El id es: " +mapaCriaturas.get(k).getID());
    if(mapaCriaturas.get(k).getFortaleza() == N){
      x.put(mapaCriaturas.get(k).getID(),mapaCriaturas.get(k));
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando dices que no te funciona, cual es el resultado actual comparado con el esperado?

Comment: Ni siquiera me compila

Comment: Podrias editar tu pregunta para incluir el error que te da al compilar?

Comment: A ver si así se ve un poco mejor

Comment: Como podras ver en los errores de compilacion, el problema no se encuentra en tu logica, sino en la manera que instancias los HashMaps. Los HashMaps requieren que les indiques que tipo de valor sera su llave y su contenido `HashMap<TipoLlave,TipoContenido>`. Veo que lo haces en la mayoria, pero el error te indica el numero de linea donde pudiste haberlo olvidado.

Answer (score 0):

- para empezar debes mejorar lo basico:

```
Map<String, Criatura> mapaCriaturas = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Criatura> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Criatura> x = new HashMap<>();
```

- a continuacion un ejemplo que se compila y funciona

```
    void test_2() {
        Map<String, Criatura> mapaCriaturas = new HashMap<>();
        mapaCriaturas.put("xyz", new Criatura("abc", 'N', "aaa"));
        mapaCriaturas.put("zzz", new Criatura("def", 'X', "aaa"));
        Map<String, Criatura> map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Criatura> x = new HashMap<>();

        Set<String> keys = mapaCriaturas.keySet();
        keys.forEach(k -> {
            if (mapaCriaturas.get(k).getFortaleza() == 'N') {
                x.put(mapaCriaturas.get(k).getID(), mapaCriaturas.get(k));
            }
        });
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```